# How can i show pagenavi in my author.php?

Tags: wp-query, author, php, plugin-wp-pagenavi

With this query in author.php i show all posts from a specific author_id/name/slug.
But the problem is when i set the minimum of posts to show in the page.

I have tried with posts_per_page= but if i set for example 6(for show last 6 posts) and i put my pagenavi code at the end of the foreach, i can't see the pagenavi. And also another problem is that it count the six posts only for a specific blog_id and not for all blogs_id.

This is my code:

```
         <?php 
  $original_blog_id = get_current_blog_id(); // prendi blog corrente 
  $bids = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15); // inserisce l'ID nell'Array 

 foreach($bids as $bid):
       switch_to_blog($bid); //switch

   ?>





       <?php

       $posts = get_posts('author='.$curauth->ID.'&posts_per_page=6');
       foreach($posts as $post): setup_postdata($post);
       ?>


<?php
endforeach ;

switch_to_blog( $original_blog_id ); //switched back to current blog
?>



</ul>



<!-- End Loop -->
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    <?php if (function_exists ('wp_pagenavi')) {wp_pagenavi ();};?> 




<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by using a query/loop other than the main query loop in `author.php`? Does your pagination work properly if you use the main loop/query?

Comment: I can't see pagination also if i use only the main loop query.

Comment: If i change posts_per_page=6 to posts_per_page=-1 i can see the pagenavi but the problem is that there are all posts, without the restriction of number of posts per page.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the WP-PageNavi plugin, there are several FAQs on using it with a secondary query loop:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/faq/

this code is from one of the pages linked from that FAQ:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query( array( 'tag' => 'foo', 'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ) );

while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
    the_title();
    // more stuff here
endwhile;

wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $my_query ) );

wp_reset_postdata();
```

specifically, they want you to retrieve the current page number:

```
get_query_var('paged')
```

and pass it into the paging function:

```
wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $my_query ) );
```

I just created an author page on a test site, with a new WP_Query with a specified author, posts_per_page set to 2, and get_query_var('paged'). The page displayed 2 posts from the specified author, with the spiffy navigation at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Ok, i have try to implement this solution in my code but doesn't display the pagenavi. Maybe i wrong something..if you watch my code how can i fix it?

Comment: Can you edit your original question with your updated code?